# Every (finite) group having a central series is nilpotent.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

The statement is from Kurzweil and Stellmacher, The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction, as well as the following:

(a) A group $G$ is nilpotent if every subgroup of $G$ is subnormal in $G$. Equivalently $U\lt N_G(U)$ for every $U\lt G$. (Page 99)

(b) 5.1.2 Let $G$ be a group and $Z$ a subgroup of $Z(G)$. Then $G$ is nilpotent iff $G/Z$ is nilpotent. (Page 100)

Now he says (page 102): 5.1.2 shows that every group having a central series is nilpotent. But I can't see how to use 5.1.2. Let $1=Z_0\leq Z_1 \leq ... \leq Z_{r-1} \leq Z_r=G$ be a central series. Where do I find a quotient of $G$ that is nilpotent?

Comment: The proof is by induction on $r$.

Comment: Case $r=1$: then $Z_1/1\leq Z(G/1)$, $Z_1\leq Z(G)$. But $Z_1=G$. Then $G$ is abelian and every subgroup of $G$ is subnormal in $G$, which is the definition of nilpotency. For $r\gt 1$, $Z_r/Z_{r-1}\leq Z(G/Z_{r-1})$, so $Z_r/Z_{r-1}$ is abelian and so nilpotent. This is all I see.

Comment: For general $r$, $G/Z_1$ has a central series of length $r-1$, which means...?

Comment: Which means, by the inductive hypothesis, that $G/Z_1$ is nilpotent and then 5.1.2 gives $G$ nilpotent because $Z_1\leq Z(G)$. But where is the central series for $G/Z_1$?

Comment: @stf91: It’s $Z_1/Z_1\leq Z_2/Z_1\leq\cdots$

Comment: I just want comment that "a group which has a central series" is the more general definition of nilpotent group. It occurs that for finite groups it is equivalent to (a) and (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly, given your definition of nilpotent.

Let $U$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Then there exists a largest $j$ such that $Z_j\subseteq U$. Since $U$ is proper, $j\lt r$. Then $Z_{j+1}\nsubseteq U$. Since $Z_{j+1}/Z_j\leq Z(G/Z_j)$, it follows that any element in $Z_{j+1}/Z_j$ centralizes $U/Z_j$. Thus, if $x\in Z_{j+1}$ and $u\in U$, then $xux^{-1}\in uZ_j\subseteq U$. Hence $Z_{j+1}$ normalizes $U$, so the normalizer of $U$ contains elements not in $U$ (namely, elements of $Z_{j+1}\setminus U$, which is nonempty since $Z_{j+1}$ is not contained in $U$).